# Fetch user Data using user image?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook-graph-api, twitter, google-plus

There is Any way or Method to find user information by using user image.
Suppose that: i have one person image by using this image, can we get user information from google+, facebook, and other social sites.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use Google Image search by example programatically, you might be able to do it.

In practice, the user image on other pages might look the same but they will be compressed with different algorithms, so you can't compare them byte-wise.

All in all, it is much easier to ask the user to add the info.

Answer (score 0):

You could try submitting the image to TinEye [here](http://www.tineye.com) and that does a reverse search, so it will show you all other places where that photo appears on the web.